# VkDescriptorSetLayout compatibility

Tags: vulkan

Vulkan specification says the following:

> Two pipeline layouts are defined to be “compatible for set N” if they
> were created with identically defined descriptor set layouts for sets
> zero through N

And I am wondering what identically defined descriptor set layouts means ?
Does it mean that two descriptor set layouts can be identically defined even if they are not the same VkDescriptorSetLayout handle ?

The reason I am asking is that I want to make use of binding descriptor sets by frequency of use to make it as efficient as possible. However I am not sure if that also means that I have to make sure that I use only one VkDescriptorSetLayout handle for every unique descriptor set in my application.

An example to illustrate more clearly what I mean:

I have a pipeline A with VkPipelineLayout A with only one VkDescriptorSetLayout A, which has only one uniform buffer binding.
I also have a second pipeline B with VkPipelineLayout B with only one VkDescriptorSetLayout B, which has also has only one uniform buffer binding.
And I have allocated one VkDescriptorSet A based on VkDescriptorSetLayout A.

Do I have to allocate and bind VkDescriptorSet B when I switch to pipeline B ? Or will VkDescriptorSet A remain bound ?

Answer (score 1):

The term "identically defined" is actually [*defined* in the Vulkan specification's glossary](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/chap60.html#glossary):

> Objects of the same type where all arguments to their creation or allocation functions, with the exception of pAllocator, are
>
> - Vulkan handles which refer to the same object or
> - identical scalar or enumeration values or
> - Host pointers which point to an array of values or structures which also satisfy these three constraints.

Basically, two Vulkan object handles are identically defined if they were created using objects that have identical contents.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That seems like answer to my questions is yes they can be identically defined and not be the same VkDescriptorSetLayout handle at the same time and VkDescriptorSet A from my example should remain bound, correct ?